# unable to add category in creating post dynamically

Tags: php

I have the code for adding post dynamically, and it's working properly:

```
$title = "Hello world";

$create_post = array(
        'post_title' => $title ,
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'mypost_type' 
    );

$post_id = wp_insert_post($create_post);
```

However, if i add the code below, no category is added to the post created.
38 and 39 is the id's of an existing category.

```
wp_set_post_categories( $post_id , array(38,39), false );
```

Here is my registered post type and taxonomy:

```
 ##POST TYPE
    register_post_type('mypost_type' , array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __('MyPost'),
            'singular_name' => __('MyPost')
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'mypost_type'),
        'supports' => array('author','editor','thumbnail','title','excerpt','page-attributes'),
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-money'

    ));

    ###TAXONOMY
    register_taxonomy('mypost-cat',
        array('mypost_type'),
        array(
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __('My Post Type Categories', 'taxonomy general name'),
                'singular_name' => __('My Post Type Categories', 'taxonomy sing name'),
                'menu_name' => __('Categories')
            ),
            'show_admin_column' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'mypost-cat')
        )
    );
```

I hope you can help me to solve this issue, thanks

Comment: Are `38` and `39` _categories_? Or are they `mypost-cat`s? `wp_set_post_categories()` is for setting the `category` taxonomy. If you want to set terms from a custom taxonomy use [`wp_set_post_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_post_terms/).

Comment: @JacobPeattie, 38 and 39 are id of my category, i used wp_set_post_categories because i want to set category to my added post type.

Comment: So like I said, you should use wp_set_post_terms().

Comment: @JacobPeattie im getting an error, Invalid taxonomy in wp_set_post_terms

Comment: What are you setting for taxonomy?

Comment: @JacobPeattie, mypost-cat

Comment: When are you using this function, what hook?

Comment: @JacobPeattie, i used add_action init